# Chrome displays "Potentially Dangerous" error message for PDF file, how can I fix this?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I need to post a rental agreement on to my website and I set up a link to that specific asset file. I designed it in InDesign, then exported the file as a PDF. I tested the link and chrome prompts that the PDF file is "**potentially dangerous**".

It is a two page document so I can't put it in an image format.

Is there anyway that I can **re-export it** so my viewers can view the PDF file and yet don't think my website is potentially dangerous?

Comment: Is Google reporting any other pages on your domain as "potentially dangerous"? It seems odd that it would only flag a PDF extension.

Comment: If you can, try your PDF on another domain.

Comment: @zigojacko Only when you open up the PDF.

Comment: @w3d I tried it on my main domain, then on the subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using something other than InDesign to create the PDF,maybe try Microsoft Word,or perhaps LibreOffice if you are using Linux.